# App crashes while passing Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, nullreferenceexception, customdialog

I have a custom dialog activity which asks user to enter OTP. I then do the normal working of OTP process by checking if it was correct and so on.

Now when i am done with it, i want to open the next activity which i am not able to open.

My code for the Custom dialog is:

```
public void showOTPDialog(Activity activity, String otp) {

    this.activity = activity;
    this.otp = otp;

    dialog = new Dialog(activity);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.verify_otp);

    final EditText etOtp = dialog.findViewById(R.id.et_otp);
    Button verify = dialog.findViewById(R.id.bt_go);
    Button resend = dialog.findViewById(R.id.bt_resend);

    verify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // verify if the otp entered was correct
        }
    });

    resend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //send new otp
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    if (window != null) {
        window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

}

private class insertOTP extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        pDialog.setMessage("Kindly wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            // RPS for inserting few things
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);
        pDialog.dismiss();

        if (response.equals("success")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("class","1");
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "This user already exists...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error when i try to give an intent and start SecondActivity.
The error is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3918)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:68)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:751)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4168)
    at com.globaltradingcompany.bhhopu.AuthenticateActivity$insertUser.onPostExecute(AuthenticateActivity.java:128)
    at com.globaltradingcompany.bhhopu.AuthenticateActivity$insertUser.onPostExecute(AuthenticateActivity.java:82)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I tried adding AuthenticationActivity.this,getApplicationContext(),getContext() inside the first argument of Intent. None seem to work.

A little help would be appreciated. Let me know if you need anything else

Comment: try this library https://github.com/kostasdrakonakis/android_navigator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach to call the second activity from the asynctask
When initializing the object of asynctask pass the current class reference as parameter

```
private class insertOTP extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

private Activity activity;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

   public insertOTP(Activity activity) {
      this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        pDialog.setMessage("Kindly wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            // RPS for inserting few things
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);
        pDialog.dismiss();

        if (response.equals("success")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("class","1");
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "This user already exists...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this approach also but didn't work. I don't understand why progress dialog and toasts are taking activity properly but while passing intent it shows null object reference.

Comment: Can you please share the code from where you are passing the activity object reference in asynctask.

Comment: I got the answer i am posting it

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I was giving the base activity's intent but starting the activity from the current activity which was causing the error.

Solution:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("class","1");
        activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I have mentioned same in my answered... It's not a new answer.. :)